# Batch return to last tag

Tags: batch-file

I've been fiddling around with Batch based on what my friend has taught me (as far as I can see, it is very minimal) and so I'm not really sure how to go about this. My problem is basically, when trying to go from `:label1` to `:error`, I'd have to create a new `:error` for every label, e.g. `:label2` would need `:error2`.

I'm almost certain that there is a less cluttered way of doing this, but I'm also pretty sure that there is no way to return to last tag
Here is an example of my problem (notes are in `[]` parentheses). Keep in mind that I have minimal knowledge with batch, so pretty much everything I make is very cluttered and uses simple commands

```
@echo off

:main
echo Hello, please select an option
echo 1) Start
echo 2) Quit [will be left without a label in this example]
set /p input=
if %input%==1 goto start
if %input%==2 goto quit
goto error

:start
echo Welcome
echo Select 1) Girl or 2) Boy
set /p input=
if %input%==1 [not important]
if %input%==2 [not important]
goto error2

:error
echo Error
pause
goto main

:error2
echo Error
pause
goto start
```

So, my problem is the creation of more errors. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables in the `goto` statement just like anywhere else.

So store the label of current stage in some variable, then go to that label in the error handler, like this:

```
@echo off

:main
echo Hello, please select an option
echo 1) Start
echo 2) Quit [will be left without a label in this example]
set current_label=main
set /p input=
if %input%==1 goto start
if %input%==2 goto quit
goto error

:start
echo Welcome
echo Select 1) Girl or 2) Boy
set current_label=start
set /p input=
if %input%==1 [not important]
if %input%==2 [not important]
goto error

:error
echo Error
pause
goto %current_label%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Aphoria would have the right answer here for simple common sense, but this was an example and not my actual problem, so this works slightly better. Thanks both of you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jumping to an error label, just `ECHO` your message and jump back to `:main`.

```
@echo off

:main
echo Hello, please select an option
echo 1) Start
echo 2) Quit [will be left without a label in this example]
set /p input=
if %input%==1 goto start
if %input%==2 goto quit
echo Error
pause
goto main
```